# Could I have thread safety problems using this aproach?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, thread-safety, ejb

I'm working with EJB/JPA and I've created a static method called createDataset that will lookup for a Dataset object. Each time that I have to insert, update, remove, etc an entity, I retrieve a DatasetObject calling DatasetFactory.createDataset() and I call the appropriate method (insert, update, etc).

The codes:

```
public class DatasetFactory {
    public static Dataset createDataset() {
        try {
            return (Dataset) new InitialContext().lookup("java:global/.../Dataset");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}

public interface Dataset<T> {
    void insert(T entity);
    //...
}

@Stateless
@EJB(name = "java:global/.../Dataset", beanInterface = Dataset.class)
public class DatasetBean<T> implements Dataset<T> {

    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void insert(T entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
    }
    //...
}
```

Could I have thread safety problems using this aproach? If so, what modifications should I have to do? Should I put the synchronized modifier in the DatasetFactory.createDataset()?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You don't ever have to synchonize any method of an EJB, because the EJB specification  specifies that an EJB instance may not be called by two concurrent threads. The EJB container handles the synchonization and thread safety for you. That's one of the points in using EJBs.

Answer (score 1):

From a thread-safety point of view, your code looks good.

But it looks like you are implementing a DAO (Data Access Object) just you are calling your DAO a Dataset instead and it is not a good idea to implement DAOs using EJBs as the EJB container loads and verifies all your EJBs at startup and this can slow things down. And usually EJBs keep only a certain number of EJBs in memory (EJB pool) but if you don't implement your DAOs as EJBs you can create as many of them as you want and Java's GC cleans them up for you.

Comment: @joaosavio if you configure your container to, say, create at max 5 instances of the bean but more than 5 users use your app at the same time, you could encounter some performance problems (starvation). However, what I've mentioned in my answer, is that when your app server start up, it should create and verify all your EJBs and this can slow down the "start up time", not the performance of the running app.

Answer (score 0):

if your entitymanager is thread-save then there is no risk with using your insert method

Comment: An entityManager is not thread-safe, but an EJB may never be called by two woncurrent threads, so it's not a problem.